# Django model is not saving to Database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-database

I have a very simple model containing just four fields: `meeting_date`,`meeting_hour`, `participant_name` and `participant_email`. I'm sending email about selected data, hour to participant, it works. But this schedule is not writing to database. Here are my codes:

`views.py:`

```
def index(request):
    context = {
        'schedules': Schedule.objects.all()
    }
    participant_name = request.POST.get('name')
    participant_email = request.POST.get('email')
    meeting_date = request.POST.get('date')
    meeting_hour = request.POST.get('hour')
    subject = 'Görüş'
    message = 'Hello ' + str(participant_name) + '. \nDate: ' + str(meeting_date) + ' hour ' + str(meeting_hour).
    from_email = settings.SERVER_EMAIL
    recipient_list = [participant_email]
    send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list)
    if request.POST.get('participant_email'):
        Schedule.objects.create(
            participant_name = request.POST.get('name'),
            participant_email = request.POST.get('email'),
            meeting_date = request.POST.get('date'),
            meeting_hour = request.POST.get('hour')
        )
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

`admin.py`:

```
class ScheduleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['participant_name', 'participant_email', 'is_scheduled', 'meeting_date', 'meeting_hour']

admin.site.register(Schedule, ScheduleAdmin)
```

`models.py`:

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    participiant_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    participiant_email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    meeting_date = models.DateField()
    meeting_hour = models.TimeField()
    is_scheduled = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.meeting_date
```

`html`:

```
<form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label><br/>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="date">Date</label><br/>
                    <input type="date" name="date">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="hour">Saat</label><br/>
                    <select name="hour" id="hour">
                        <option value="1">Hour</option>
                        <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
                        <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
                        <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
                        <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
                        <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: it looks like Schedule is not created because you are passing meeting_date and meeting_hour as string but the model is defining those two fields as DateField and TimeField. Also consider creating ModelForm for Schedule as it validates users input for you.

Comment: @Yellowduck you say I'm sending dates as string. Where it happens ? Where should I do the changes ? Btw, I've tried ModelForm method, but didn't know what to use for TimeField. Is there any widget that lets choose hour and minute ?

Answer (score 0):

`request.POST.get('date')` and `request.POST.get('hour')` are strings, so you will to convert them back to `date` and `hour` as such:

```
from datetime import datetime

converted_meeting_date = datetime.strptime(request.POST.get('date'), "%Y-%m-%d")
converted_meeting_hour = datetime.strptime(request.POST.get('hour'), "%H:%M")
```

Note that the date and hour formats have to align with the formats in your POST data, after the conversion you should be able to create Schedule object:

```
 Schedule.objects.create(
            participant_name = request.POST.get('name'),
            participant_email = request.POST.get('email'),
            meeting_date = converted_meeting_date,
            meeting_hour = converted_meeting_hour 
        )
```

Comment: Man, I tried your method, but I'm getting an error: ```strptime() argument 1 must be str, not None```

Comment: are you sure you are passing the arguments correctly? The error states either your `request.POST.get('date')` or `request.POST.get('hour')` is returning None

Comment: Man, hello, have a good day. Can you check please my this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61156491/django-form-save-is-not-creating-modelform ? Last days my question reach very few people, and can't tag someone. Please, help me.